# Unable to resolve service in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

im new comer in asp.net and this is my hello world example and i wanna have a GET api and get data from mysql database and return it to client. this is my controller that i used dependency injection for get connection with database:

i used this command for create dbcontext and scaffold required files:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=webApiTest;User Id=root;Password=000;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models/
```

my database name is `WebApiTest` for having no error it seems i have to register the auto generated file `WebApiTestContext` for using it in my UserController as dependency

i have no Startup.cs as default so i made it and this is my Startup.cs for registering `WebApiTestContext` as service in container:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3;

    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<WebApiTestContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(_configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString")));
        }
    }
```

and this is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication3.DTO;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers;
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly WebApiTestContext dbContext;
    
    public UserController(WebApiTestContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetUsers")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<UserDTO>>> Get()
    {
        var List = await dbContext.Users.Select(s=> new UserDTO
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            FirstName = s.FirstName,
            LastName = s.LastName,
            UserName = s.Username,
            Password = s.Password,
            EnrollmentDate = s.EnrollmentDate,
        }).ToListAsync();
        if (List.Count < 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return List;
    }
}
```

i get this error and i have no idea about it.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplication3.Models.WebApiTestContext' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication3.Controllers.UserController'.
```

and this is `WebApiTestContext`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication3.Models;

public partial class WebApiTestContext : DbContext
{
    public WebApiTestContext()
    {
    }

    public WebApiTestContext(DbContextOptions<WebApiTestContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
        => optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("Server=localhost;Database=webApiTest;User Id=root;Password=000;");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");

            entity.ToTable("user");

            entity.Property(e => e.EnrollmentDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
            entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasMaxLength(45);
            entity.Property(e => e.LastName).HasMaxLength(45);
            entity.Property(e => e.Password).HasMaxLength(45);
            entity.Property(e => e.Username).HasMaxLength(45);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

could you help me?

Comment: Please post the code of `WebApiTestContext`.

Comment: @SNBS post editted

Comment: Try calling `services.AddDbContext<WebApiTestContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped)` instead in `Startup.cs`. The connection string is already configured in `OnConfiguring` in the context.

Comment: like this?using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3;

    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<WebApiTestContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
        }
    }
still same error

Comment: What type of database are you using? I saw `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models/` in your command, and `UseMySQL` in your code.

Comment: Most importantly, what version of Asp.Net are you using? The 'Startup.cs' file was removed in .Net 5 onwards, and the configuration is now done directly in 'Program.cs' to simplify things. If you've manually added a Startup class to do your DI registration, it won't be used. You can check this by putting a breakpoint in the 'ConfigureServices' method and see if it is hit

Comment: Really, thanks @AndrewWilliamson, forgot about this. If you use the newest version i.e. ASP.NET MVC 6, the dependency injection is performed in `Program.cs` before the `builder.Build` call, like this: `builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebApiTestContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);`. And, as an experiment (if the error persists), you could try adding the `DbContext` service directly, without `AddDbContext`: `builder.Services.AddScoped<WebApiTestContext, WebApiTestContext>();`.